# Set Company name in From field of Phone call activity when opening from Opportunity form

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-365

In opportunity form under activity notes and PVR section, we have the option to create a phone call activity. Our requirement is that when we open a phone activity from there by default "From" should be prepopulated with the associate company name of that opportunity.
We have tried workflow and using related opportunity records but it only works when we save phone calls record and not on page load.
We have also try javascript but nowhere able to find the related opportunity data. We have also used regardingId (as suggested on some URL) but that field is also coming as null.

Any pointer would be highly appreciated.

Comment: If anyone needs a similar requirement then check the below solution. From regardingObjectId which is available in Phone Call activity form, get opportunity id and from there make a  web API call to fetch associated contract and then set in "TO" column.

Comment: post it as answer.